# Javascript - add more parameters to a callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, asynccallback

I'm calling an async function that needs a callback function as parameters.

Here is the javascript code:

```
for(i in array) 
{
    var item = array[i];
    functionToCall(item[i][1], 50, function(a, b)
    {
        alert(a + b);
    });
}
```

I cannot edit functionToCall function. What I want to do is using the "item" variable in the callback function like this.

```
for(i in array) 
{
    var item = array[i];
    functionToCall(item[i][1], 50, function(a, b, c)
    {
        alert(a + b + c);
    }, item);
}
```

But this code doesn't work properly. I cannot just use "item" inside the function because it is always using the last item in array.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `item` inside the function, but you need to "capture" it so that you don't end up using the last element of the array everytime.

```
for(var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; ++i) { // better than for .. in
    var item = array[i];
    (function(item, i){
      functionToCall(item[i][1], 50, function(a, b) // do you really re-index item with the same index?
      {
          alert(a + b);
      });
    })(item, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use `for..in` to iterate arrays.  Instead use `.forEach()` and a lot of your problems just go away:

```
array.forEach(function(item)
{ 
    functionToCall(item[1], 50, function(a, b) 
    { 
        alert(a + b + item[1]); 
    }); 
}
```

To use `.forEach()` in older browsers, [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach#Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
 function createExecutionCall(itemIndex, number, item)
 {
      return function() { functionToCall(itemIndex, number, function(a, b)
      {
           // Example, item should be contained within this closure then
           alert(a + b + item);
      });
 }

 for(i in array) 
 {
     var item = array[i];

     var call = createExecutionCall(item[i][1], 50, item);
     call();
  }
```